# Integration notation

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

could someone explain the following notation:
$u(x,t):=\int^t_0 v(x,t:\tau)d \tau$

It's come up but I don't understand how to interpret the semicoloned tau

Comment: You interpret the semicolon exactly like a comma. It serves no mathematical purpose. It's only a visual aid intended to help you keep straight which variables are important for a given problem.

Comment: Can we get a bit more of the context? What is $v$, for example?

Comment: I would guess $v(x,t:\tau)=v(x,\tau)$, $t:\tau$ meaning "replace $t$ with $\tau$"

Comment: Replace $t$ with $\tau$ is more coherent, I think. Otherwise we would have $t$ in the limit of integration AND in the integrand. I don't know if this could cause some confusion.